# Uninstalling VMware Player 17 Issue on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: uninstall, virtualization, vmware

I have accidentally executed these commands:

```
sudo rm -r /etc/vmware
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/vmware
```

Before executed this one sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player, so when I tried to executed sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player I got this message:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
The VMware Installer cannot continue if there are running virtual machines. Shut down or suspend running virtual machines before continuing.  Press 'enter' to continue.
```

When I press enter, the same message is display,
I have tried to find running vmware program to kill them but nothing, so I decided to reinstall Vmware player but the issue still remain.

Could you please help me with this problem? Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please explain in more detail the relation between the `sudo rm -r ...` commands and the install commands. The relation or what you believe is the relation is not clear.
Please also add details in which release of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I don't know the relation between the sudo rm -r ... and the installation, but probably they are files created during the installation process because when I wanted to completely uninstall VMware player from my machine, on the product documentation the tell us to use these above commands after using the uninstallation command sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting and starting the installation again?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.